# Making constrained optimization feasible by changing constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints, minimization, convex-optimization

Given a constraint maximization problem,

```
Minimize Objective J
s.t.  a < wx < b
```

Sometimes this problem is not feasible because of the tight constraint: a < wx < b

So we would want to relax the constraint a bit to make the problem feasible, then minimize for the objective.

```
Minimize Objective J
s.t.  a-epsilon_a < wx < b+epsilon_b
```

where epsilon_a and epsilon_b are small numbers to make the problem.

How do we find epsilon_a and epsilon_b prior to minimizing the objective J?

Comment: why not using a solver supporting equality constraints w.x=a ?

Comment: I would want to relax the two inequality constraints a little as possible to make the problem feasible.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Thank you for thinking about this problem Picaud

Comment: another thing not clear to me is:  a,b are two scalars, and w,x two vectors? or a,b,x are three vectors and w a matrix?

Comment: In general to find a feasible starting point, you completely drop the objective function an use your solver to minimize ||w.x-1/2(a+b)||^2 . You will find a x that will be as close a possible to 1/2(a+b) -> did you try this kind of approach?

Comment: Yes. a,b are scalars, w,x are vectors. Sorry I should have clarified. Yes. I see your approach. Actually that makes sense. Empirically that should work. Thank you Picaud!

Comment: In real optimization modeling we often make constraints elastic. This means we allow to violate them at a cost. E.g. a manpower constraint be be violated, but the cost is equal to hiring temp workers. A production capacity constraint can be violated, but the cost is equal to outsource production.